# why my calendar always return current hour?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, calendar

I have this code:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            now.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new Date(image.date));


double score = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
```

I have ont time: `image.date = 1407918131283` and another time `image.date = 1407925331901`. But `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` always returns `11`. Why is that?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a short but complete program which *only* demonstrated the problem, and didn't do anything with other fields etc. We will also need to know which time zone your calendar is in...

Comment: changed. thanks for the remark

Comment: That's still not a short but complete program. I'd expect to be able to copy and paste a short but complete program into a text editor, compile it, run it, and witness the problem. It's not clear why there need to be two calendars involved, either.

Answer (score 1):

Use JodaTime for time manipulations. It is pretty much a replacement for flawed internal java classes

```
  final String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
  final String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";
  final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  final DateTime dt1 = format.parseDateTime(dateStart);
  final DateTime dt2 = format.parseDateTime(dateStop);

  System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays() + " days, ");
  System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
  System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
  System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(1407918131283l);

        System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        cal.setTimeInMillis(1407925331901l);
        System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Here it gives different hour of the day. Check your other code.

Wed Aug 13 13:52:11 IST 2014

13

Wed Aug 13 15:52:11 IST 2014

15

Note: Check your calendar is set to the proper time before you retrieve the hour of the day

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> calendar.setTime(new Date(image.date));
> double score = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) - now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
> ```

Hard without knowing how and when "calender" and "now" were created. Be aware that you should create Calendar instances with [getInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29).

i.e.:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(image.date));
```

Also, you can check the timestamps using a shell:

```
[~]$ LANG=C date -d @1407925331
Wed Aug 13 12:22:11 CEST 2014
[~]$ LANG=C date -d @1407918131
Wed Aug 13 10:22:11 CEST 2014
```

But even better, use Marcins answer, JodaTime. It's easier and less flawed.